# AutomationElement ScrollBar throws Access Violation on ScrollVertical

Tags: c#, ui-automation, microsoft-ui-automation

I am attempting to use the following code to scroll a scrollbar in a third party .net application. When I run the code in visual studio, it throws an access violation. When I execute the assembly outside visual studio, it says Unsupported Pattern.... Any ideas are greatly appreciated =]

```
if(child.Current.ClassName == "ScrollBar")
{
    PropertyCondition condition = new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.AutomationIdProperty, child.Current.AutomationId);
    AutomationElement btnElement = child.FindFirst(TreeScope.Element, condition);
    ScrollPattern btnPattern = btnElement.GetCurrentPattern(ScrollPattern.Pattern) as ScrollPattern;
    btnPattern.ScrollVertical(ScrollAmount.LargeIncrement);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Few checks that i would have done:

1. Null check missing for your btnElement.
2. Make sure Scroll bar is actually present(Scroll pattern is not exposed unless pane size exceeds window size-if designed that way).
3. lastly, instead of directly getting pattern as ScrollPattern, try GetAllSupportedPatterns from bthElement, make sure Scroll Pattern is actually present.